# Illegal override of UIMovieClip in mx.flash.UIMovieClip

Tags: apache-flex, flash, runtime-error

I have no clue how to fix this problem... Please help.

I have Flex application that loads another Flex SWF.
I have changed the SWF being loaded after one year I haven't touched it. It was all working fine, but suddenly after the change, when the SWF is being loaded, it is stuck and I get the error:

**VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of UIMovieClip in mx.flash.UIMovieClip.**

Thats it, it doesn't give me any more clues on where the problem is.

I hope someone can help me with it.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you change to different Flex SDKs with your latest update?  How is the SWF being loaded?  ( Using SWFLoader, or as a Module or something else?)

Comment: I am building it locally, and I build both SWFs with the default SDK 4.5.1. I am loading the SWF with "mx:SWFLoader". I have noticed that the application is Flex project and the the loaded SWF is ActionScript project. Maybe it is related to that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the UIMovieClip is from a different release then the UIMovieClip you compile against. The UIMovieClip's implementation may differ from 3.a.b to 3.x.y.

Comment: UIMovieClip adds the behaviour for MovieClips similar to UIComponent to make it compatible with the framework regarding lauyouting, sizing etc.